# Why does this not align my elements correctly?

Tags: css, layout, html

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/styles/base.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id= "top-nav">
        <h1>Sitename</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Feed</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

#

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

#top-nav{
background-color: Gray;
width: 100%;
height: 135px;
padding: 0 0 0 0;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
}


#top-nav h1{
    float: left;
    margin: inherit;
    padding-right: 700px;

}

#top-nav ul{
    float: left;
    bottom: 0;
}

#top-nav li{
    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

What I would like my layout to be, is to have the h1 vertically aligned in the center of the top-nav div and I would like the ul to be on the right of the page at the bottom of the top-nav. Why am I getting unexpected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your nav being on the bottom of the top-nav element, you could use the absolute property, so it always be fixed at the bottom.
Don't use a float left for the H1 as the previous answer say.
For your h1 being align vertically, you can try different padding to get what you want (or you can make a more complicated scaffolding by using the display:table ...)
But the more simple is that :

```
#top-nav h1{
        padding-top:30px;
        display:inline-block;
        width:auto;
        vertical-align:middle; 
}


#top-nav ul{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    right:5px;
}
```

does it answer ?

edit

Comment: It somewhat answers it. Why does the padding-top, when changed, affect the position of the ul?

Comment: yeah you right, i missed something, sorry. I'm looking on what is wrong on my code.

Comment: ok, i display the h1 inline-block and put a width:auto, so it won't "push" the nav element. Is that ok for you now ?

Answer (score 1):

The `padding-right: 700px` rule in `#top-nav h1` is pushing the `ul` element off-position.

Something like this should work:

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0; /* You can just have one 0 instead of "0 0 0 0". */
    margin: 0;
}

#top-nav {
    background-color: Gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
}

#top-nav h1 {
    float: left;
    line-height: 135px; /* Set to the height of #top-nav */
    margin: 0;
}

#top-nav ul {
    float: right;
}

#top-nav li {
    text-align: right;
    display: inline;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Why does the line-height property get set to the height of the parent?

Comment: That'll vertically align the `<h1>` element.

Answer (score 0):

could it be due to the space you've got in

`<div id= "top-nav">`

after "id=" ?

also, instead of using `padding-right: 700px;` for h1 element, just float the `ul` element to the right.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways you can achieve what you want. F.e., for vertical aligning the `h1` in the middle of `#top-nav`:

```
#top-nav h1 {
    ...
    line-height: 135px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and for aligning the `ul` at the bottom of `#top-nav`:

```
#top-nav {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
#top-nav ul {                           
    ...
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems because you are using layout elements incorrectly.  The `<ul>` element is for unordered lists, not for menus containing links.  Also, using `float` is highly discouraged because it was only intended to be used to have text wrap around an image and not for layout.  Floats have to be cleared and don't work well cross-browser.

The trick here is to use absolute positioning and make sure that the value is relative to the container, so you have to set the `#top-nav` div to have `position: relative` otherwise its children will be positioned relative to the first *positioned* parent element, which is most likely the body element in this case.

This works fine for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/gc3EY/1/

HTML:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="top-nav">
             <h1>Sitename</h1>
        <span>
            <a href="#">Feed</a>
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
            <a href="#">Settings</a>
        </span>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden;}

div#top-nav span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 97%;
}
div#top-nav span a {
    padding: 0 2px;
}
div#top-nav {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
div#top-nav h1 {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```